# Sum in a textbox with calculated values

Tags: reporting-services, sum, footer

I have got a Column (Weight) which is multiplied by the amount. I need an extra textbox in the footer which shows the Sum of Weight. But I only get the weight of the non multiplied data. Is it possible to SUM the weight without the footRow for the tablix?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly get the name of your textbox in properties then you add textbox in your footer and add this:

```
ReportItems![Text Box name].Value
```